# Saving User object into another object

Tags: grails, groovy

My `User` domain class looks as:

```
String name
String age
String gender
boolean status
```

If the User's `status` field is `true`,   i need to add all those Users to the following domain class `Participant`

```
String eventName
String schoolAttended
User user
```

What i tried so far:

```
// To get all users
User.findAll("from User as u where u. status =?", [true])

// To get each user and add them to `Participant`

// Save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to create new `Participant` instance for every `User` with status equal to `true`? If yes, you can use [findAllBy*](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html) to find users:

```
// get all users with status equal to true
def usersWithStatusTrue = Users.findAllByStatus(true)

usersWithStatusTrue.each { singleUser ->
    // create and persist participant for each user
    def participant = new Participant(user: singleUser, eventName: "...", schoolAttended: "...")
    participant.save(failOnError: true) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would accomplish the task with a single `insert from select` type of SQL query

UPDATE:

see [MySql refdoc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/insert-select.html) for example. You can fire the following SQL-commando:

```
Sql db = new Sql( dataSource )
db.execute "insert into participant ( user_id, event_name ) select user.id, 'some_event_name' from user"
db.close()
```

Note, that if you have to create the records, using the `user.id` only my example is fine. Should you need to get other values from different sources for you `Participant` class, then you should stick with #pawel-piecyk's answer, as it provides more power for the price of performance